# Why can't I access Konva Canvas properties in my React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, konvajs

I am using the FabricJS library with ReactJS. Here I want to create and use Konva.Canvas constructor methods. But, I have a problem while accessing the Konva Canvas properties.

**if I use canvas.add method I get ERROR canvas.add is not a function**

```
const Konva = window.Konva;
class Canvas extends Component {
    state ={
        canvas: null,
        width: null,
        height: null,
        layer: null,
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const canvas = new Konva.Canvas({ 
            container: this.c,
            height:this.props.height,
            width:this.props.width
        });
        console.log(canvas);
        const layer = new Konva.Layer();
        this.setState({canvas,layer});
        // canvas.add(layer);
        layer.draw();
    }
```

Comment: Yes. If I use canvas.add method. It says canvas.add is not a function. I am not getting any properties from an instance. I am

Comment: Please add that information to your question.

Comment: Hello, I have made silly mistake used Canvas instead of the Stage. It has been solved. Thank You. isherwood

Comment: Glad to hear. Please provide and accept an answer or delete your question so hundreds of people don't stop by trying to help. :)

Comment: I have replaced  const canvas= new Konva.Stage({})

Comment: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). That's not an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Replaced

```
 const canvas = new Konva.Canvas({ 
        container: this.c,
        height:this.props.height,
        width:this.props.width
    });
```

with

```
 const canvas = new Konva.Stage({ 
        container: this.c,
        height:this.props.height,
        width:this.props.width
    });
```

Stage supports add method. More info on https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Stage.html#main